# master checkbox not changing visual state when using jQuery's toggle

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I'm using jQuery to check/uncheck all checkboxes in a div, and it works fine, but the master checkbox doesn't seem to get clicked (i.e. I can't see the check mark go on and off), how can I fix this?

This is the code I have so far:

```
jQuery(function () {
jQuery('#select_all').toggle(
    function() {
        jQuery('#elementos .c_e').prop('checked', true);
    },
    function() {
        jQuery('#elementos .c_e').prop('checked', false);

    }
);});
```

Thanks.

Here's a live version: http://jsfiddle.net/L8DVu/

Comment: Could you please make a fiddle demonstration?

Comment: I just added a fiddle demo guys, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you are making to complex, you can do it with single statement,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8DVu/1/)**

```
jQuery('#select_all').click(function() {

    jQuery('#elementos .c_e').prop('checked', this.checked);

});​
```